# make session regeneration available to all login strategies method of passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to implement `session regeneration` once the user logs-in to the application with the following code ,i am fairly able to implement.

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err || !user) {
      res.status(400).send(info);
    } else 
    {
        req.login(user, function (err){
            if (err) res.status(400).send(err);
            else 
            {
                req.session.regenerate(function(err) 
                {
                    if (err)     console.log(err);
                    else{
                        //reset the cookie header with new session id
                        //return the user object
                    }      
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

As Passport offers log-in through various strategies so i have to implement the same thing in all the other `strategies` ..I want to narrow it down with minimum code changes in the application ,I know i can place it in a method ..but is there some other solution which will affect all the login methods of all strategies which are implemented and which will be implemented in future.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: till now i have managed to achieve this by making changes in the `SessionManager.prototype.logIn` method present in `passport node module`.